# What can I use to retrieve the area that a user marks on an image in my app?

Tags: java, android

My app takes a picture of the user and I want the user to mark where their eyes, mouth, and ears are on the image. The ears are just one point but the mouth is a selection of the whole mouth area

I have got the taking a picture part done but how can I go on about allowing the user to highlight he mouth area and then get those pixels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html has details on using touch events, which you'll need to understand and implement.